# Optimize function with if and for loop

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba

I have two function. One calls the other. Here is the complete code and data on which the two functions are running.

```py
import numpy as np

agents={(-71.60000000000002, 41.1): 1, (-71.40000000000003, 41.90000000000001): 1, (-71.80000000000001, 41.2): 1, (-71.20000000000005, 41.400000000000006): 1, (-71.30000000000004, 41.50000000000001): 1, (-71.70000000000002, 41.70000000000001): 1, (-71.50000000000003, 42.000000000000014): 1, (-71.50000000000003, 41.2): 1, (-71.40000000000003, 42.000000000000014): 1, (-71.20000000000005, 41.60000000000001): 1, (-71.70000000000002, 42.000000000000014): 1, (-71.50000000000003, 41.60000000000001): 1, (-71.40000000000003, 41.50000000000001): 1, (-71.50000000000003, 41.90000000000001): 1, (-71.70000000000002, 41.50000000000001): 1, (-71.40000000000003, 41.80000000000001): 1, (-71.30000000000004, 41.60000000000001): 1, (-71.70000000000002, 41.80000000000001): 2, (-71.60000000000002, 41.60000000000001): 2, (-71.20000000000005, 41.50000000000001): 2, (-71.50000000000003, 41.70000000000001): 2, (-71.40000000000003, 41.400000000000006): 2, (-71.50000000000003, 41.80000000000001): 2, (-71.80000000000001, 41.400000000000006): 2, (-71.30000000000004, 41.400000000000006): 2, (-71.40000000000003, 41.70000000000001): 2, (-71.60000000000002, 41.80000000000001): 2, (-71.70000000000002, 41.90000000000001): 2, (-71.30000000000004, 41.70000000000001): 2, (-71.60000000000002, 41.90000000000001): 2, (-71.60000000000002, 42.000000000000014): 2}
all_houses=[(-71.60000000000002, 41.70000000000001), (-71.70000000000002, 42.000000000000014), (-71.20000000000005, 41.400000000000006), (-71.60000000000002, 41.1), (-71.50000000000003, 41.70000000000001), (-71.50000000000003, 41.90000000000001), (-71.30000000000004, 41.400000000000006), (-71.30000000000004, 41.60000000000001), (-71.40000000000003, 41.90000000000001), (-71.80000000000001, 41.300000000000004), (-71.70000000000002, 41.300000000000004), (-71.60000000000002, 41.2), (-71.30000000000004, 41.70000000000001), (-71.60000000000002, 41.90000000000001), (-71.40000000000003, 41.400000000000006), (-71.60000000000002, 42.000000000000014), (-71.50000000000003, 41.50000000000001), (-71.50000000000003, 42.000000000000014), (-71.70000000000002, 41.90000000000001), (-71.70000000000002, 41.80000000000001), (-71.50000000000003, 41.60000000000001), (-71.40000000000003, 41.50000000000001), (-71.30000000000004, 41.50000000000001), (-71.70000000000002, 41.60000000000001), (-71.9, 41.300000000000004), (-71.50000000000003, 41.400000000000006), (-71.40000000000003, 41.70000000000001), (-71.60000000000002, 41.60000000000001), (-71.50000000000003, 41.80000000000001), (-71.40000000000003, 41.60000000000001), (-71.40000000000003, 41.80000000000001), (-71.80000000000001, 41.400000000000006), (-71.60000000000002, 41.80000000000001), (-71.20000000000005, 41.50000000000001), (-71.60000000000002, 41.400000000000006), (-71.60000000000002, 41.50000000000001), (-71.40000000000003, 42.000000000000014), (-71.50000000000003, 41.2), (-71.80000000000001, 41.2), (-71.70000000000002, 41.400000000000006), (-71.20000000000005, 41.60000000000001), (-71.70000000000002, 41.50000000000001), (-71.70000000000002, 41.70000000000001)]
empty_houses=[(-71.9, 41.300000000000004), (-71.60000000000002, 41.2), (-71.40000000000003, 41.60000000000001), (-71.70000000000002, 41.400000000000006), (-71.80000000000001, 41.400000000000006), (-71.50000000000003, 41.60000000000001), (-71.70000000000002, 41.300000000000004), (-71.20000000000005, 41.50000000000001), (-71.40000000000003, 42.000000000000014), (-71.40000000000003, 41.80000000000001), (-71.50000000000003, 41.50000000000001), (-71.60000000000002, 41.80000000000001)]
agent=[-71.50000000000003, 42.000000000000014]
spacing=0.1
similarity_threshhold=0.21

def is_unsatisfied(x, y,all_houses,agents,spacing,empty_houses):

        """
        Checking if an agent is unsatisfied or satisified at its current
        position.
        """

        race = agents[(x,y)]
        count_similar = 0
        count_different = 0
        min_width=min(np.array(all_houses)[:,0])
        max_width=max(np.array(all_houses)[:,0])
        min_height=min(np.array(all_houses)[:,1])
        max_height=max(np.array(all_houses)[:,1])

        if x > min_width and y > min_height and (x-spacing, y-spacing) not in empty_houses:
            if (x-spacing, y-spacing) in agents:
                if agents[(x-spacing, y-spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if y > min_height and (x,y-spacing) not in empty_houses:
            if (x,y-spacing) in agents:
                if agents[(x,y-spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x < (max_width-spacing) and y > min_height and (x+spacing,y-spacing) not in empty_houses:
            if (x+spacing,y-spacing) in agents:
                if agents[(x+spacing,y-spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x > min_width and (x-spacing,y) not in empty_houses:
            if (x-spacing,y) in agents:
                if agents[(x-spacing,y)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x < (max_width-spacing) and (x+spacing,y) not in empty_houses:
            if (x+spacing,y) in agents:
                if agents[(x+spacing,y)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x > min_width and y < (max_height-spacing) and (x-spacing,y+spacing) not in empty_houses:
            if (x-spacing,y+spacing) in agents:
                if agents[(x-spacing,y+spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1  
            else:
                pass
        if x > min_width and y < (max_height-spacing) and (x,y+spacing) not in empty_houses:
            if (x,y+spacing) in agents:
                if agents[(x,y+spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass
        if x < (max_width-spacing) and y < (max_height-spacing) and (x+spacing,y+spacing) not in empty_houses:
            if (x+spacing,y+spacing) in agents:
                if agents[(x+spacing,y+spacing)] == race:
                    count_similar += 1
                else:
                    count_different += 1
            else:
                pass

        if (count_similar+count_different) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return float(count_similar)/(count_similar+count_different) < similarity_threshhold

def find_unsatisifed(agents,all_houses,spacing,empty_houses):       
    for agent in agents:
        print(is_unsatisfied(agent[0],agent[1],all_houses,agents,spacing,empty_houses))

find_unsatisifed(agents,all_houses,spacing,empty_houses)
```

I would like to optimize both the `find_unsatisfied` and `is_unsatisfied`. functions to run faster as I have to deal with at least 5000 elements of data in the variable agents and all houses and atleast 400 in the empty_houses.

`is_unsatisfied` takes the coordinate of an agent and check if all the agents around it on a grid are of same race or not. (race in this case are either 1 or 2).
`find_unsatisfied` takes the agents dictionary and runs `is_unsatisfied` function on every agent which is necessary.

I have tried numba but it is not working as these functions are actually the methods in a class and gets their data with the geopandas library which is not supported by numba. Then i tried to create a function outside of the class and pass it in but that is not really working as the loop doesn't really run. I did it like this

```
from numba import jit, autojit, int_, void, float_,bool_

@jit()
def is_unsatisfied_numbized(instance, x, y):

    """
    Checking if an agent is unsatisfied or satisified at its current
    position.
    """

    race = instance.agents[(x,y)]
    count_similar = 0
    count_different = 0
    min_width=min(np.array(instance.all_houses)[:,0])
    max_width=max(np.array(instance.all_houses)[:,0])
    min_height=min(np.array(instance.all_houses)[:,1])
    max_height=max(np.array(instance.all_houses)[:,1])

    if x > min_width and y > min_height and (x-instance.spacing, y-instance.spacing) not in instance.empty_houses:
        if (x-instance.spacing, y-instance.spacing) in instance.agents:
            if instance.agents[(x-instance.spacing, y-instance.spacing)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        else:
            pass
    if y > min_height and (x,y-instance.spacing) not in instance.empty_houses:
        if (x,y-instance.spacing) in instance.agents:
            if instance.agents[(x,y-instance.spacing)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        else:
            pass
    if x < (max_width-instance.spacing) and y > min_height and (x+instance.spacing,y-instance.spacing) not in instance.empty_houses:
        if (x+instance.spacing,y-instance.spacing) in instance.agents:
            if instance.agents[(x+instance.spacing,y-instance.spacing)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        else:
            pass
    if x > min_width and (x-instance.spacing,y) not in instance.empty_houses:
        if (x-instance.spacing,y) in instance.agents:
            if instance.agents[(x-instance.spacing,y)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        else:
            pass
    if x < (max_width-instance.spacing) and (x+instance.spacing,y) not in instance.empty_houses:
        if (x+instance.spacing,y) in instance.agents:
            if instance.agents[(x+instance.spacing,y)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        else:
            pass
    if x > min_width and y < (max_height-instance.spacing) and (x-instance.spacing,y+instance.spacing) not in instance.empty_houses:
        if (x-instance.spacing,y+instance.spacing) in instance.agents:
            if instance.agents[(x-instance.spacing,y+instance.spacing)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1  
        else:
            pass
    if x > min_width and y < (max_height-instance.spacing) and (x,y+instance.spacing) not in instance.empty_houses:
        if (x,y+instance.spacing) in instance.agents:
            if instance.agents[(x,y+instance.spacing)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        else:
            pass
    if x < (max_width-instance.spacing) and y < (max_height-instance.spacing) and (x+instance.spacing,y+instance.spacing) not in instance.empty_houses:
        if (x+instance.spacing,y+instance.spacing) in instance.agents:
            if instance.agents[(x+instance.spacing,y+instance.spacing)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        else:
            pass

    if (count_similar+count_different) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return float(count_similar)/(count_similar+count_different) < instance.similarity_threshhold

class geo():

  def __init__(self):
        #parameters in here

  def is_unsatisfied(self,x,y):
        is_unsatisfied_numbized(self, x, y)

  def update_normal(self):

        for i in range(100):
            n_changes = 0
            for agent in self.agents:
                if self.is_unsatisfied(agent[0], agent[1]):
                    n_changes += 1
            print(n_changes)
            print(i)
            if n_changes == 0:
                break
```

This thing doesn't work.

Are there any ideas what I did wrong there or any other suggestions to optimize the two functions without numba. Maybe with vectorize operations with numpy.

Answer (score 0):

In order to optimize the functions without numba, you can do the following:

**1. Prevent to test the same condition twice**

Instead of checking like you did

```
If A and B:
    Do X
If A and C: 
    Do Y
```

, you can group if statements together such as

```
If A:
    If B: 
        Do X
    If C: 
        Do Y
```

**2. Decrease conditional complexity. You test often**

```
if X not in empty_houses:
   if X in agents:
       Do A
```

,which you can simplify to

```
targetList = [i for i in agents if i not in empty_houses]
if X in targetList:
    Do A
```

Comment: Any suggestion with numpy?